# Onclick with Fragment , there's no error but it doesn't work

Tags: android, onclick, fragment

```
public class frag2 extends Fragment {

    Button btn_service;

    @Override

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View good = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container, false);
        ((EditText) good.findViewById(R.id.editText)).setText("edit text test");


        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container,
                false);

        btn_service = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn_service.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "test snackbar button", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }

        });
        return good;
    }
```

I want to know how to code onClick with Fragment layout.
I'm a novice in android coding. so I may ask the wrong question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating two separate views `good` and `v` but you only need `good` , `v` is just there , doing nothing because `good` is the the actual fragment view which will be displayed in your activity (due to  `return good`) so you need to bind your action with the child of `good`

From [inflate (int resource, 
                ViewGroup root, 
                boolean attachToRoot)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate(int,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20boolean))

> Inflate a new view hierarchy from the specified xml resource.

```
//final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment2, container,
//        false);

btn_service = (Button) good.findViewById(R.id.btn);
//                     ^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved the problem! I'll accept your answer asap

Comment: i am glad that i could help , happy coding